# How do you use .push or set to create a new child key in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, api, firebase

I have some location data with the following structure.

```
[business:
     Joes Pizza:{
accountid:1818
address:32, Angle des Rue des Nimes et Blvd. Toussaint Louverture,
city:Anytown
country:USA
created:At10/26/2015 7:27:42 PM
heading: Fast Food
headingid: 178
latitude: 18.572203
longitude:-72.306747
name: Joes Pizza 
objectId:x9VRotBU2O
phonenumber:1 509 473 6003
website:http://pizza.com
    },
]
```

I am trying to reformat the geo-code info for all businesses that have it by reading the separate lat and long info and using `push()` to write a `latLng` object containing both keys.

I am able to create the object and log it to the console but when I try to call the object on the business object, its undefined. I attempted this via `set()` and `push()` in the firebase docs.

I tried the version below as well as `fb.child('latLng').push({lat: snapshot.val().latitude, lng: snapshot.val().longitude});`. Can not get it to go.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.0/firebase.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Geoloc</p>
<script>
var fb = new Firebase("https://crackling-fire.firebaseio.com/business");

// Retrieve relevant data
fb.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var place = snapshot.val();
  var latLng = {lat: snapshot.val().latitude, lng: snapshot.val().longitude}
  if (place.hasOwnProperty('longitude') && place.hasOwnProperty('latitude'))
    {

    fb.child('latLng').push(place.latLng);

    console.log(place.name, place.latLng);
    console.log(latLng);
    };
  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two mistakes that I can see:

1. You're setting your `latLng` as a child of your root `fb` reference
2. You're using `push()` for a structure that seems to be a *named child*

Solution for these two:

```
fb.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var place = snapshot.val();
  if (place.hasOwnProperty('longitude') && place.hasOwnProperty('latitude')) {
    snapshot.ref().child('latLng').set({lat: place.latitude, lng: place.longitude});
  };
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Frank. If by latLng is named you mean that it is already a property on the object im pushing to, that is not the case. I am creating a new key and value for each object if it already has lat and long properties. Is your solution still recommended in that case? Thanks again. This solution worked. Thank you.